# Javascript, merge 2 objects, but loop through specific fields through formatting functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, format

These objects could be anything, but as long as they have a TYPE field, we can run them through a function. I'm trying to save on repeating my code to format data. Once when I put it into a database, and once when I pull it out. And depending on which table of data, we use similar functionality. This kind of works, but it doesn't seem very optimal. Is there a better way to map fields / values / formatters?

```
const fields = {
      title: null,
      slug: '', // slugify the TITLE field
      content: null,
      featured_image_url: null,
      price: {
        type: 'currency' // run this function on the value given
      },
      billing: {
        first_name: 'justin'
      }
    }

// This could be data coming from a form, and it will need to be formatted etc.
const data = {
  title: 'New Title',
  price: 9,
  billing: {
    first_name: 'John'
  }
}  

function currency (value) {
    return '$' + value
}

function formatData (fields, data) {
  for (const [field, def] of Object.entries(fields)) {
    if (typeof def === 'object' && def !== null) {
      for (const [f, d] of Object.entries(def)) {
        if (f === 'type') {
          if (data && data[field]) {
            data[field] = [d](data[field])
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return data
}
  
const newData = formatData(fields, data)
console.log(Object.assign(fields, newData))
```

Any direction would be helpful on how to deal with this.

Comment: I can't get your code to run in the snippet so am not sure of your expected output, can you put that in your question

Comment: Basically the FIELDS is default data, the "DATA" is the stuff to override it. But I also want to run "functions/methods" on the data to be formatted (IE: currency) that I showed there. Does that clear it up a bit?

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing for me. Can you add expected output as well in your question.